# How can I process a text file line by line and split it's parameters to variables using c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

if I have a text file like that:

- READ  RESW   1
- TR    RESW   10
- LDA    Make
- Do    BYTE   1

I tried something like that :

```
while (infile >> label >> opcode >> operand)
```

but the problem is when a label doesn't exist like in line 3, the program waits till it get's it's  third parameter from the next line.
How can I fix that?

Comment: If you know which lines, then keep track of the lines and use conditionals at the appropriate points.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read lines and then extract the values from the lines. In this way you wont read from the next line if the last parameter is not present:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        std::string label;
        std::string opcode;
        std::string operand; 

        std::stringstream{ line } >> label >> opcode >> operand;

        std::cout << label << " " << opcode << " " << operand << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If there is no operand then `operand` string will be empty.

Also you can do this:

```
int operand = INT_MAX;
std::stringstream{ line } >> label >> opcode >> operand;
if(operand == INT_MAX) {
    // no int operand found
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to read the complete line from the file and then use `strtok` to split the `label`, `opcode` and `operand`

```
string str;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
while ( getline (myfile,str) )
    {
        char *pch;
        pch = strtok (str," ");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
          printf ("%s\t",pch);  // This will print the values which can also be stored in variables.
          pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
    }
myfile.close();
```

Comment: The `strtok` function is not guaranteed to work with `std::string`.  The `strtok` function works with arrays of characters, and modifies the arrays.

Comment: If you live dangerously, you could use `strtok(str.data(), " ");`.